# How to put an if statement inside a variable?

Tags: php

```
$galleryDetails .='
        <div class="col-md-3 product-left">

  <p class = "tb">Total Bid: if($rowSelectCountTotal > 0){$rowSelectCountTotal}else {0}</p>
</div>
```

Above is my code , i try to put if else statement inside the variable but cant work,how can i put the if else inside the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
$galleryDetails .='
        <div class="col-md-3 product-left">

  <p class = "tb">Total Bid: '.(($rowSelectCountTotal > 0) ? $rowSelectCountTotal : 0)'.</p>
</div>
```

<sup>*This is called [Shorthand if/else](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples), and allows you to achieve what you're trying to do.*</sup>